# Margin between span/div blocks not setting to 0px

Tags: html, css

I have some `span/div` blocks with width and height  defined and display set to `inline-block` but there is some gap between those blocks so i used `margin:0px;` but there is still gap i have to use negative margin value to remove that gap.
Here is the code i am using

```
//HTML SPAN BLOCKS//
<body>
<span class="pro" id="1"></span>
<span class="pro"></span>
<span class="pro"></span>
<span class="pro"></span>
<span class="pro"></span>
<span class="pro"></span>
<span class="pro"></span>
<span class="pro"></span>
</body>

//CSS//

body{margin:0px;}
.pro{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #FF0004;
    margin:0px;
    padding:0px;
}
#1{
    background:#FF0004;
}
```

and i am giving background with id but its not working. Margin between span blocks works is 0 (when set to 0) in internet explorer.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/jrv4zp5d/)

When i add some content(text) in those tags whole layout is messed up . All blocks moves up and down from its position

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Comment: since you've put each span on its own line in the code, and since all whitespace gets truncated to a single space, there are literally `&nbsp;` characters in between your span elements. you can put them [all on the same line](https://jsfiddle.net/a2r1g98w/) or set the parent's font-size to 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. id's that start with a number will not work in css, unless you [escape them](https://css-tricks.com/ids-cannot-start-with-a-number/) in your stylesheet (which I wouldn't advise). So I would suggest changing your id to something like `#p1` and you should be fine.
2. inline(-block) elements take whitespace into account. If you remove the whitespace from your markup, or set the font-size to 0, the spacing between the blocks should disappear. Or you could turn them into `block` elements as well.

And your updated fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/jrv4zp5d/2/

Answer (score 2):

this space between `inline-block` elements is caused by `font-size` of the parent, in your case the `BODY` element. To fix this issue set `font-size` of the parent element to `0` then define new `font-size` inside `.pro` elements.

Here is the solution without affecting `font-size` of body element by wrapping content with `.clearGaps` container.

https://jsfiddle.net/jrv4zp5d/1/

html:

```
<div class="clearGaps">
    <span class="pro" id="1"></span>
    <span class="pro"></span>
    <span class="pro"></span>
    <span class="pro"></span>
    <span class="pro"></span>
    <span class="pro"></span>
    <span class="pro"></span>
    <span class="pro"></span>
</div>
```

css:

```
body{
    margin: 0px;
}
.clearGaps {
    font-size: 0;
}
.pro{
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid #FF0004;
    font-size: 12px; /* restore font size after clearing gaps */
}
#1{
    background:#FF0004;
}
```

Good luck

Answer (score 1):

CSS:

```
span {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

HTML:

```
<span>This will have</span>
<span>a gap between the elements</span>

<span>This won't have</span><span>a gap between the elements</span>
```

originally @Juan G. Hurtado

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, for a CSS only approach, you can try changing the display of .pro to block and specify a float.

```
.pro{
width:300px;
height:300px;
display:block;
float:left;
border:1px solid #FF0004;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
```